# Asp.net Grid view Filling Through Jquery Resulting in Error Alert My Code Attached?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-services, gridview

hi i m trying to fill grid with jquery but it is alerting error my webservice code is fine for getting data as i tried it before by returning as string through webservice but when i try for filling data grid resulting error even its not debugging webservice as its not firing it ???

first i use grid in my code as,

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDetails" runat="server">
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#DC5807" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />
</asp:GridView>
```

then i creat rows on table in code behind as,

```
   private void BindColumnToGridview()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("user_Id");
            dt.Columns.Add("user_Fullname");
            dt.Columns.Add("user_Need");
            dt.Rows.Add();
            gvDetails.DataSource = dt;
            gvDetails.DataBind();
            gvDetails.Rows[0].Visible = false;
        }

  if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                BindColumnToGridview();
            }
```

then i get id from session and pass it to webservice as shown below,

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var empId = '<%= Session["UserID"] %>';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
alert(empId);
        $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "ServiceGetUser.asmx/BindDatatable", 
        data: "{'employeeId': '" + empId + "'}",
        dataType: "json", 
        success: function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
        $("#gvDetails").append("<tr><td>" + data.d[i].user_Id + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].user_Fullname + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].user_Need + "</td></tr>");
        }
        },
        error: function(result) {
        alert("Error");
        } 
        }); 
        }); 

</script>
```

my web service as,

```
   [WebMethod]

        public static UserDetails[] BindDatatable(string employeeId)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            List<UserDetails> details = new List<UserDetails>();

            UserSearch us = new UserSearch();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            Connection cs = new Connection();
            ds = cs.CurrentStatus(employeeId);

                    foreach (DataRow dtrow in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
                        user.user_Id = dtrow["user_Id"].ToString();
                        user.user_Fullname = dtrow["user_Fullname"].ToString();
                        user.user_Need = dtrow["user_Need"].ToString();
                        details.Add(user);
                    }

            return details.ToArray();
        }
        public class UserDetails
        {
            public string user_Id { get; set; }
            public string user_Fullname { get; set; }
            public string user_Need { get; set; }
        }
```

it is alerting id and after that it alerts "error" and not debbuging webservice even dont know whats going wrong ???

i have included jquery library as it was not because of it

i get this as example from,

```
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/03/bind-data-to-gridview-with-jquery-or.html
```

Hopes for your suggestions

Comment: no its not firing debug just alerting "error"

Comment: @waiting for Suggestions :(

Comment: is that true `ds = cs.CurrentStatus(employeeId);` ??? or it will be `ds = us.CurrentStatus(employeeId);` .... I don't know exactly...

Comment: @SAC its fine but debugger not working on webservice code then the issue you mention me would come later ???

Comment: I have created a project same as yours and put a break point and debug project then break point triggers... So, I don't know why in your project it not triggers... It should not trigger if some problem in calling WebService (may be in jQuery which can be debug by FireBug )...  Thats only my view as I am not well experience on this...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24120/discussion-between-sac-and-syed-raza)

Comment: i sicken tired after the whole day and now doing it by some different trick

Comment: now debugger working but not appending object value in return from webservice to grid view